# Heroku- 10k Row limitation

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Does Heroku Database 10k row limitation applicable for a single app or for a single Free account ? 
If I am making multiple apps having different databases then the row limitation will divide in all or 10k per app database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10K row limitation is for the [Heroku Postges](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) Database as a Service add-on. The free tier of that service is the [hobby-dev](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#hobby-tier) plan, which gives you max. 10K rows per free DB instance.
So if you have multiple apps in your Heroku account each of which uses their own Heroku Postgres DB with the `hobby-dev` plan, then each app will be able to populate 10K rows in their DB.

Comment: And is it also possible to attach multiple databases with a single app? Like for example I have 5 apps with 5 different databases having 10k rows and I want to use all databases in one app ? I searched on the documentation and found some 'config var' does they do the same thing?

Comment: I believe that is possible. However, management of that may be pretty tricky. Only one database instance would be referenced via the DATABASE_URL env var. Note that for just $9/month you could upgrade to a hobby-basic plan, which would give you 10,000,000 rows, and would be much simpler to manage than 5 separate instances.

Comment: Ohk Thanks alot :)